# SQL: Drop Views When Table is Dropped

Tags: sql, sql-view

Is there a standard SQL command that when a table is to be dropped, it drops all the views on it as well?

Comment: which database? tag it

Comment: @GurwinderSingh No specific database, I know how to do it in each database type, but I'm trying to find a way that works on all, that's why I said a "standard SQL command" :)

Comment: The only way I could see to do this would be to build a procedure that accepts as input the table name and database then loops though dependencies of each view looking for that table and if found, drops the view.  As each database implements their own method of listing dependencies, you would have to write logic specific to each database.  I personally see no other way.

Comment: In Postgres, use the `cascade` option but there is nothing that works on "all" DBMS (actually you will not find too many non-trivial statements that work on "all" DBMS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard way to drop a table and all associated views.  I know Postgres has a `CASCADE` option but that's implementation specific - MySQL accepts `CASCADE`  but does absolutely nothing with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a standardized command across all rdms that will drop a table and it's bounded view(s) in one operation.

Comment: That's wrong. In Postgres you can use the `cascade` option to drop the views

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer to note that there is no standardized command. Here is the Postgres drop command with the CASCADE options. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-droptable.html